# A program that prints its input one word per line

Tags: c

I want to print one word per line but the output is not printing the last character of each word. Can anyone help in finding the error?

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#define IN 1  /* Inside a text */  
#define OUT 0  /* Outside a text */ 
main()  
{  
    int c,nw,state;  
    state=OUT;  
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF) 
    {  
       if(c==' '||c=='\n'||c=='\t')  
       {  
            state=OUT;  
            printf("\n");                      
       }  

       else if(state==OUT)  
       {  
            putchar(c);   /* To print the first character */
            state=IN;  
            ++nw;  
            c=getchar();  
            putchar(c);  /* To print the other characters of the word*/
       }    
    }  
}
```

Using the above code the last character of each word is not printed.

Comment: You're not looping on the output. Why not `putchar` each character as you see it, then when you see the space or tab, output the `\n`? You don't need that `state` and the extra `if` stuff...

Comment: To make the `state` stuff work correctly, the code should be structured as `if (state == IN) { do_stuff_for_In_state } else { do_stuff_for_Out_state }`. The current code doesn't do anything when `state==IN`.

Comment: Note: only need to `printf("\n");` when `state` _changes_  from `IN --> OUT`

Comment: With `c=getchar();   putchar(c); /* To print... `, code does not know `c` is a non-space.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger (`gdb`) to run step by step your program and find the bug. Also, define *exactly* what is a word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sample to fix

```
#include <stdio.h>  

#define IN  1 /* Inside a text */  
#define OUT 0 /* Outside a text */ 

int main(void){
    int c, nw=0, state=OUT;

    while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
        if(c==' ' || c=='\n' || c=='\t'){//if(isspace(c)){
            if(state == IN){
                state = OUT;
                putchar('\n');
            }
        } else {
            if(state == OUT){
                state = IN;
                ++nw;
            }
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
    //printf("\n%d\n", nw);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it can be solved without maintaining the states..Suggestions are welcomed

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    int c;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        if(c==' ' || c=='\t' || c=='\b')
        {
            printf("\n");
            while(c==' ' || c=='\t' || c=='\b')
            c=getchar();
        }
        if(c!=EOF)
        putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If input is `" 123\n"`, this answer prints 2 lines rather than the expected 1.

Comment: If input is "123 456" this prints 1 line `"123\n"` and then the beginning of another line without a trailing `'\n`'.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the solution

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c, inspace;
    inspace = 0;


    while ((c=getchar())!= EOF) 
    {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')
        {
            if (inspace == 0)
            {
                putchar('\n');
                inspace = 1;
            }
        }

        else 
        {
            putchar(c);
            inspace = 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If input is " 123\n", this answer prints 2 lines rather than the expected 1.

Comment: If input is "123 456" this prints 1 line "123\n" and then the beginning of another line without a trailing '\n'

Answer (score 0):

```
for( ; (c = getchar()) != EOF; )
{
    flag = 0;
    if(c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' ')
        { state = OUT;

          }
    else if(state == OUT){
         flag = 1;
         state = IN;
        }
    if(flag == 1 && count!=0)
       putchar('\n');

    if(state == IN)
        putchar(c);

    count++;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
        char ch;
        while((ch=getchar())!=EOF){
            if(ch!='\n' && ch!=' ' && ch!='\t'){
                putchar(ch);
            }
            else{
                putchar('\n');
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

 int main(){
   int c;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)      
       if(c=='\t'|| c=='\n' || c==' ')
             putchar('\n');
                else
                   putchar(c);

          return 0;
  }
```

Comment: If input was `" \t abc\n"` this would print 4 lines: 3 of `"\n"` and 1 `"abc\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

> A program that prints its input one word per line

OP's code is certainly amiss with the following with the `c=getchar(); putchar(c);` as it prints `c` be it a letter, space, `'\n'` or `EOF`.

```
else if(state==OUT) {  
  putchar(c);
  state=IN;  
  ++nw;  
  c=getchar();  
  putchar(c);  // Error to print without testing `c`
}
```

Only a few changes needed following OP `state` idea.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define IN 1  /* Inside text */
#define OUT 0  /* Outside text */

int main(void) {
  unsigned long long wc = 0;  // no need for a narrow `int`, how about something wider?
  int state = OUT;
  int ch;
  while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (state == OUT) {
      if (!isspace(ch)) {
        wc++;        // new word begun
        state = IN;
        putchar(ch);
      }
    } else /* state == IN */ {
      if (isspace(ch)) {   // add test
        putchar('\n');
        state = OUT;
      } else {
        putchar(ch);
      }
    }
  }
  if (state == IN) { // add test in case last word not followed by a white-space
    putchar('\n');
  }
  printf("Word count:%llu\n", wc);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a version of @BLUEPIXY answer only addition is where it prints the characters before separating the words on a new line, and where it pads a newline at the end of the printed characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define IN 1  /*Inside of a text*/
#define OUT 0 /*outside of a text*/
#define SPACE ' '
#define NEWLINE '\n'
#define TAB '\t'

int main()
{
  int nw = 0, c, state = OUT;

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
  {
    if (c == SPACE || c == NEWLINE || c == TAB)
    {
      /* Pads the last character(a new line) with another new line */
      if (c == NEWLINE)
      {
        putchar('\n');
      }
      if (state == IN)
      {
        state = OUT;
        putchar('\n');
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if (state == OUT)
      {
        state = IN;
        ++nw;
      }
      putchar(c);
    }
  }
  printf("\nTotal word count: %d\n", nw);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the comments said this was solvable without the #defines or flags. It is possible, indeed. And it makes the code so much shorter. This my solution:

```
int main()
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c != ' ')
        {
            putchar(c);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uses `state` but only one call to `getchar`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int main() {
    int c;
    int state;

    state = OUT;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n') {
            state = OUT;
        } else if (state == OUT) {
            state = IN;
            putchar('\n');
            putchar(c);
        } else if (state == IN) {
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN  1
#define OUT 0

main()
{
    int state;
    int c;
    state = OUT;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if ((c != '\n') && (c != ' ') && (c != '\t')) {
            putchar(c);
            state = IN;
        }
        else if (state == IN) {
            putchar('\n');
            state = OUT;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and clean.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int main(void)
{
    int c,state;
    state = IN;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t')
        {
            state = OUT;
        }
        else if (state == OUT) 
        {
            putchar('\n');
            state = IN;
        }
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have state, a simple program like below does the job:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int c;

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    
    // Check if c is a word
    if (c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n') {
      putchar(c);
    } else {
      putchar('\n');
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Exercise 1-12.** Write a program that prints its input one word per line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1 /* Inside a word */
#define OUT 0 /* Outside a word */

int main(){
    int c, nl, nw, nc, state;
    state = OUT;
    nl = nc = nw = 0;

    while ((c=getchar())!=EOF){
        ++nc;
        if (c=='\n'){
            ++nl;
        }
        if (c==' ' || c=='\n' || c=='\t'){
            state = OUT;
            putchar('\n');
            continue;
        }
        else if (state == OUT){
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
        }
        putchar(c);
    }
    printf("\nnl=%d; nw=%d; nc=%d;\n", nl, nw, nc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Don't just dump code